# html code does not appear when I set it within <%%>

Tags: html, jsp

The code is fine and has no issues
I have tried to solve the issue using out.println()

The code runs until I the section 
but then continues at  of the same class during execution within the browser

The iteration is supposed to display all the products for a specific user in order to allow for updating of the items or deletion

```html
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder"%>
<%@page import="entity.Product"%>
<%@page import="entity.Farmer"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <%
        String useremail = null;
        //allow access only if session exists
        if(session.getAttribute("useremail") == null){
                response.sendRedirect("farmlogin.jsp");
        }else{
             useremail = (String) session.getAttribute("useremail");
        }
    %>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
        <title>My products</title>
    </head>
    
        <div class = "container">
        <h1><%=useremail%> . Here are your products</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class = "row">
            <%
                SessionFactory sessionFactory;
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Farmer.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Product.class)
                    .configure();

                serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                        .build();        
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

                Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
                String hql = "FROM Product";
                Query queryy = sess.createQuery(hql);
                List<Product> products;
                List results = queryy.list();
                products = results;
                Iterator<Product> itr = products.iterator();
                if (results == null || results.isEmpty()){
                    out.println("<h3>No products available</h3>");
                }else{
                    while(itr.hasNext()){
                        Product g = itr.next();
                        System.out.println(g.vendor.getEmail());
                        String src;
                        if(useremail == g.vendor.getEmail()){
                            int prodid = g.getId();
                            if(g.getType().equals("Pineapples")){
                                System.out.println("Pineapples");
                                src = "pineapple.jpg";
            %>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="<%=src%>" alt="image" height="20px" width="20px">
                <p><%= g.getName()%></p>
                <p><%= g.vendor.getUsername()%></p>
                <form action="editprod.jsp">
                <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<%=prodid%>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Product</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <%
                }else if(g.getType().equals("Bananas")){
                    System.out.println("Bananas");
                    src = "banana.jpg";

            %>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="<%=src%>" alt="image" height="20px" width="20px">
                <p><%= g.getName()%></p>
                <p><%= g.vendor.getUsername()%></p>
                <form action="editprod.jsp">
                <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<%=prodid%>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Product</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <%
                }else if(g.getType().equals("Avocado")){
                    System.out.println("Avocado");
                    src = "avocado.jpg";

            %>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="<%=src%>" alt="image" height="20px" width="20px">
                <p><%= g.getName()%></p>
                <p><%= g.vendor.getUsername()%></p>
                <form action="editprod.jsp">
                <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<%=prodid%>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Product</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <%
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            .col-sm-4{
                border: solid 2px black;
            }
        </style>
    <%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
</html>
```

Comment: the code runs until the div class "row" then picks up after the tag is closed the rest of the html within is not displayed

Comment: there are 3 types so I need to change for each

Comment: if there were two I would have used one

Comment: I've even tried to completely remove String src and instead writing the name directly in then placing the source directly within the html

Comment: thank you for the feedback but apparently the issue was not the if condition not the if statement if( g.vendor.getEmail().equals(useremail)){} this worked over if(useremail == g.vendor.getEmail()){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue was the if condition**

if( g.vendor.getEmail().equals(useremail)){} this worked

over if(useremail == g.vendor.getEmail()){}

```html
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder"%>
<%@page import="entity.Product"%>
<%@page import="entity.Farmer"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <%
        String useremail = null;
        //allow access only if session exists
        if(session.getAttribute("useremail") == null){
                response.sendRedirect("farmlogin.jsp");
        }else{
             useremail = (String) session.getAttribute("useremail");
        }
    %>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
        <title>My products</title>
    </head>
        <div class = "container">
        <h1><%=useremail%> . Here are your products</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class = "row">
            <%
                SessionFactory sessionFactory;
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
            %>
            <%
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Farmer.class)
                    .addAnnotatedClass(Product.class)
                    .configure();
            %>
            <%
                serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                        .build();        
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            %>
            <%
                Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
                String hql = "FROM Product";
                Query queryy = sess.createQuery(hql);
                List<Product> products;
                List results = queryy.list();
            %>
            <%
                if (results == null || results.isEmpty()){
                    out.println("<h3>No products available</h3>");
                }else{
                    products = results;
                    Iterator<Product> itr = products.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext()){
                        Product g = itr.next();
                        if(g.vendor.getEmail().equals(useremail)){
                            int prodid = g.getId();
                            if(g.getType().equals("Pineapples")){
            %>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <img src="pineapple.jpg" alt="image" height="20px" width="20px">
                <p><%= g.getName()%></p>
                <p><%= g.vendor.getUsername()%></p>
                <form action="editprod.jsp">
                <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<%=prodid%>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Product</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <%
                }else if(g.getType().equals("Bananas")){
            %>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <img src="banana.jpg"" alt="image" height="20px" width="20px">
                <p><%= g.getName()%></p>
                <p><%= g.vendor.getUsername()%></p>
                <form action="editprod.jsp">
                <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<%=prodid%>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Product</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <%
                }else if(g.getType().equals("Avocado")){
                    out.println("Avocado");
            %>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <img src="avocado.jpg" alt="image" height="20px" width="20px">
                <p><%= g.getName()%></p>
                <p><%= g.vendor.getUsername()%></p>
                <form action="editprod.jsp">
                <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<%=prodid%>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Product</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <%
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            .col-sm-4{
                border: solid 2px black;
            }
        </style>
    <%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
</html>
```

Thank you to all those who answered the question